# How is it proved that $\sum_{p\le x}\frac1p=\int_2^x\frac{d(\vartheta(t))}{t\log t}$?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, definite-integrals, prime-numbers, chebyshev-function

Let $\vartheta(x)=\sum_{p\le x}\log p$ be the first Chebyshev function. I'm self-studying analytical number theory and I'm looking for a proof that $$\sum_{p\le x}\frac1p=\int_2^x\frac{d(\vartheta(t))}{t\log t} $$

Comment: First nitpick: you need a $2^-$ on the lower bound to pick up the $p=2$ term. Furthermore, do you experience with Riemann-Stieltjes integration? This follows immediately from the definition of $\vartheta(t)$.

Comment: @Clayton Thanks, I got it... what about the $2^-$ though?

Comment: @Clayton Maybe I got that too: $2$ would miss out with the $x_i <p\le x_{i+1} $ stuff so $2^-$ just means we deliberately add it. Am I correct?

Comment: that is correct!

Comment: $\int_2^x f(t) d g(t)$ is ambiguous if $g$ is discontinuous at the integers, while $\int_{2-\epsilon}^x f(t) d g(t)$ is not. You should investigate the case $g(x) = 1_{x > n}$.